# How to Store the Data in Database from dropdown in Djngo

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am working on student management project and I am unable to get the branch for student as it is foreignkey of Course model to Student model and I want to get the selected option into student model in branch row

**models.py:**

```
class Course(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    course = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    course_code = models.BigIntegerField(null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.course

class Student(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    branch=models.ForeignKey(Course,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    middle_name=models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
    roll_no=models.IntegerField()
    mobile_no=PhoneNumberField(default='')
    parents_mobile_no=PhoneNumberField(default='')
    division=models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True)
    batch=models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name + " " + self.user.last_name
```

**views.py:**

```
def studentregister(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        first_name = request.POST['first_name']
        middle_name = request.POST['middle_name']
        last_name = request.POST['last_name']
        email = request.POST['email']
        branch= request.POST['branch']
        division = request.POST['division']       
        roll_no = request.POST['roll_no']
        mobile_no = request.POST['mobile_no']
        parents_mobile_no = request.POST['parents_mobile_no']
        pass1 = request.POST['password']
        pass2 = request.POST['confirmpassword']
        
        if pass1 == pass2 :
            if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                return HttpResponse('User already exsits')
            else:
                user = User.objects.create_user(email=email, password=pass1, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)
                user.save();
                studentdetails = Student ( user=user, middle_name=middle_name,roll_no=roll_no,mobile_no=mobile_no,parents_mobile_no=parents_mobile_no, branch=branch,division=division)
                studentdetails.save();
                return render (request, 'ms/homepage/index.html')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('password does not match')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('failed')

def staffstudent(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.user_type==3:
        courses = Course.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'ms/staff/student.html',{'courses':courses})
    else:
        return render(request,'ms/login/login.html')
```

**html file as student.py:**

```
<form action="studentregister" method="POST" style = "background-color:#011B3C;">
            {% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-group" name="branch">
            <select >
                <option selected disabled="true">Branch</option>
                {% for course in courses%}
                <option>{{course.course}}</option>
                {%endfor%}
            </select>
            </div> 
</form>
```

**The error I am getting is
MultiValueDictKeyError at /staff/studentregister
'branch'**

Please help me with this as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't named that `<select>` (`<select name="branch">`) so any choice you make in it will not be transmitted to the server, and that's why you get a key error.

In addition, the `<option>`'s value must be the course's id:

```
<option value="{{ course.id }}">{{ course.course }}</option>
```

... so you can look it up in the view:

```
branch = Course.objects.get(id=request.POST['branch'])
```

However, *please* look at [Django's built-in forms functionality](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/), especially model forms – you would be done in a fraction of the HTML and Python code you have now, plus you'd actually have correct data validation.

Comment: I tried doing same i got the error       Cannot assign "'Computer Science'": "Student.branch" must be a "Course" instance.

Comment: Please see my edit. Again, all of this would be automatic with model forms.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the conventional way to deal with Forms in Django although it can be done. Convention would be:

Creating a form in forms.py like so:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):

dropdown_one = forms.ChoiceField(
    label="Country",
    widget=forms.Select(attrs={"class": "selecter form-control"}),
    choices=[],
)
dropdown_two = forms.ChoiceField(
    label="Category",
    widget=forms.Select(attrs={"class": "selecter form-control"}),
    choices=[(None, '...')],
    required=True

)
```

Then use this form in views.py like so:

```
my_form = MyForm(initial={})
return render(request,{'my_form':my_form})
```

Then finally in html file:

```
        {{my_form.media}}
        {% for item in my_form %}
        <div class="form-group col-lg-2" id="dropdown-content">
          {{item.label_tag}}
          {{item}}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}  
      </div>
```

For more refer to this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/